# AddUrlSegment throws NullReferenceException in RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I am trying to use RestSharp's AddUrlSegment to sub the token in a URL

ex: "www.test.com/{someToken}/Testing"

I am using this code:

```
string theToken = "someStringToken";
restRequest.AddUrlSegment("someToken",theToken);
```

This throws a NullReferenceException, when I try to execute the request.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I figured this out. The version of RestSharp I have (NUGET), apparently does not support the method above. Also the Resource property is the one that should be getting the url that is going to be replaced so the final code is something like this.

```
string _baseUrl = "www.test.com";

RestClient client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
RestRequest restRequest = new Request();
restRequest.Resource = "/{someToken}/Testing";
restRequest.AddParameter("someToken", theToken , ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```

This piece of code works with the version I got from NUGET

Comment: what version of nuget are you using? is it windows phone?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

Here is some **alternative solution code** with passing resource in constructor and simplified method call, using **RestSharp v.104.4.0**:

```
string _baseUrl = "www.test.com";

var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
var req = new RestRequest("/{someToken}/Testing", Method.GET);
req.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
req.AddUrlSegment("someToken", theToken);
```